# How to prove $\sqrt{2 + 2cos(\frac{π}{2^{k+1}})} = 2cos(\frac{π}{2^{k+2}})$?

Tags: analysis

How can I prove this?

$\sqrt{2 + 2cos(\frac{π}{2^{k+1}})} = 2cos(\frac{π}{2^{k+2}})$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use that $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$
And squaring your equation we get
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k+1}}\right)=2\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{k+2}}\right)-1$$

Comment: Thanks! I proved it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dr. Sonnhard Graubner I was able to prove the equation.

[image]